# Problems using CURL within a shell script

Tags: curl, ash

I'm having a problem using CURL with a shell script variable. I'm sure it's something simple I'm overlooking. I'm creating a URL that's appended with the MAC address of the Linux box. Once I have the URL built, I'm trying to pass that to curl to download a file from a remote location in to the /tmp directory of my local machine. CURL gets executed without any errors, but no data is transferred. I've tried single and double quotes around $url with no success. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Shawn

```
#!/bin/ash
config=$(ifconfig eth0 | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}')
tmp='http://abcd.com/sources.php?mac='
url=$tmp$config
curl --connect-timeout 10 --max-time 10 --retry 5 --retry-delay 0 --retry-max-time 60 -o /tmp/downloadfile $url
```

Answer (score 0):

Add [-v](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-v) to the curl command line to get to see more details of its operation (or [--trace](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--trace) if you want even more). It is plausible that the HTTP server responds with a redirect you want to follow, like with [-L](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-L).

Comment: I used -v and discovered that I was getting a "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" error. I was trying to access a domain that was being forwarded. A quick change to my DNS record solved the problem. Thank you very much for your help, -v option is good to know if you're using CURL.